# Class doesn't work if use #include with header

Tags: c++

I am trying to use my class in `main` function with hooking up

```
#include "Square/Square.h"
```

but if I do it, I have error

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>
> "Square::calculateSquare()",
>    _main in main-cac286.o
>
> "Square::Square(double)", referenced from:
>         _main in main-cac286.o
>
> "Square::~Square()", referenced from:
>         _main in main-cac286.o
>
> "Square::calculateSquare()", referenced from:
>         _main in main-cac286.o
>
> "Square::Square(int)", referenced from:
>         _main in main-cac286.o
>
> "Square::~Square()", referenced from:
>         _main in main-cac286.o

But if I use `#include Square/Square.cpp` all works perfect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: The second version isn't even a valid include directive. So I highly doubt it "works"

Comment: Please tag sensibly. C and C++ are different languages

Comment: you never should include .cpp files. Error you get is link-time error.

Comment: I don't understand why questions like this get voted down. Everyone has to start somehere, and new developers don't know why something isn't working and don't even know what to search for to find the answer.

Comment: @Andrew Henle I didn't downvote but people do that, mostly because research wasn't done, simple googling the error text  gives link to aswer that was already given. by the way,  output doesn't match gcc, neither author specified  build environment he uses (CodeBlocks, mayhaps?), so further help is impossible to give properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code

```
#include "Square/Square.h"
```

means that the contents of the file "Square/Square.h" are *included* at that point in your code.  That one line is replaced by the *entire* contents of that file.

Files such as "Square/Square.h" - a *header file* -  are usually used to *declare* things - it's a way of saying *how* something is used, or *how* it works.  Header files do not usually provide the *what*, though - that's the *definition*, apparently in this case of a square.

Have you ever traveled internationally?  Well, when you enter a country you might have to fill out a customs *declaration* - which *declares* that you have *something else*.  The *declaration* isn't the thing itself - it just says you have that thing.  That's normally what a header file does - it *declares* things that actually exist somewhere else.

So you get these error messages:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

"Square::calculateSquare()", _main in main-cac286.o

"Square::Square(double)", referenced from: _main in main-cac286.o

"Square::~Square()", referenced from: _main in main-cac286.o

"Square::calculateSquare()", referenced from: _main in main-cac286.o

"Square::Square(int)", referenced from: _main in main-cac286.o

"Square::~Square()", referenced from: _main in main-cac286.o
```

because your compiled executable *doesn't have the thing* available to it - the header file only *declared* it, it didn't *define* or *provide* it.

> But if I use `#include Square/Square.cpp` all works perfect

Because that file *defines* the *thing* - the *definition* of "square" in this case.

As others have noted, you shouldn't `#include Square/Square.cpp` - for a lot of reasons.

The simplest solution is to compile both (all) your `*.cpp` files at once.  Using `g++`, you'd do something like:

```
g++ main.cpp Square/Square.cpp -o myprogram
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work. You would still get the same problem 'undefined reference'.

Comment: @mk3009hppw And you comment is based on?

Comment: When using templates, you need to reference the actual implementation. You can't wait until the linking stage to point to the concrete implementation of a function.